# Counting the number of cubes in an isometric view

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle, 3d

I had seen questions in a sample aptitude test, where an isometric view of an object made up of cubes was given, with some of the cubes removed. We were supposed to count the number of cubes present in the diagram. Something like this,
[image]

but for more complicated isometric objects.

Another example would be puzzles such as these I suppose (note: this is a flash game, the test questions would not have the advantage of animated visual and audio clues)
[Count cubes flash game](http://coolmath-games.com/0-countcubes/)

I want to find similar sample questions, but am I am finding it difficult to look for the right keyword for a Google search.

What is the name for such puzzles?

Are there any rules or methods for finding the number of cubes in such puzzles? Or does it just come down to practice?

Answer (score 1):

Many websites show the game as "Count the Cubes" or "Count the Cubes Game", so you could try that and see what comes up.